# How many ways are there to place 24 people into two treatment groups?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to place 48 people into two treatment groups?

I thought the answer was (48 choose 24) because two treatment groups means that there will be 24 people in each group. However, the answer is supposed to be $1.6\times10^{13}$. What am I misunderstanding

Comment: It is useful to know that your answer evaluates to approximately $3.2 \times 10^{13}.$ The reason this is off by a factor of $2$ has already been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide by 2 to get the desired answer.
E.g. Consider the set {A,B,C,D}. If I wanted to split them into two groups, I could do it like so:

Group 1: {A,B}
Group 2: {C,D}

OR

Group 1: {C,D}
Group 2: {A,B}

Despite being in different groups, you get the same outcome, and hence you divide by 2!, to avoid overcounting.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that was given to you is probably wrong. I read the term "treatment group" as referring to groups, each of which is to be given one of two *different* treatments. That means that (in a smaller example) giving treatment $1$ to $\{A,D\}$ and treatment $2$ to $\{B,C\}$ is *not* to be considered the same thing as giving treatment $1$ to $\{B,C\}$ and treatment $2$ to $\{A,D\}$, even though these to choices involve the same set of groups (the same partition). So one needs to specify which $24$ out of $48$ people get the first treatment, and
$$
\binom{48}{24}=32247603683100\approx 3.25\times10^{13}
$$
is the right answer.

Comment: They really should have specified equal size, since in real situations there is often good reason not to use equal size. And the above interpretation of treatment group is the right one. For "study groups of equal size" division by $2$ would be reasonable.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You are right, it should have said so. I saw the number $24$ in the question (in fact in the title!), but had failed to observe that it was not in the cited problem statement. I don't know what "study groups" would be, but for treatments groups I cannot see how there could be equivalence between the two groups.

Comment: Oh, study group would be a group of students who help each other study. Then all I care about is who the other people in my group are.  But for treatment groups it may matter very much whether I get the placebo or not.